# Update multiple values to json file using python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, key-value

Main Json file

```
{
 "Section": [
    {
      "Update": "Y",
      "header": "Revision History",
      "setitle": " Table A",
      "subtitle": "Region 101",
      "Table": "RegionCode101",
      "Action": "InsertRegion",
      "B": "1.0.0.9.3",
      "S": "1.0.0.8",
      "C": "1.0.0.1",
      "T": "1.0.0.3",
      "I": "0.0.0.300",
      "IN": "0.0.1.491",
      "IPNB": "0.0.2.398",
      "CH": "0.0.1.258",
      "CNP": "0.0.1.491",
      "CBL": "0.0.1.4"
    },
{
          "Update": "Y",
          "header": "Revision History",
          "setitle": " Table A",
          "subtitle": "Region 101",
          "Table": "RegionCode101",
          "Action": "InsertRegion",
          "B": "1.0.0.9.3",
          "S": "1.0.0.8",
          "C": "1.0.0.1",
          "T": "1.0.0.3",
          "I": "0.0.0.300",
          "IN": "0.0.1.491",
          "IPNB": "0.0.2.398",
          "CH": "0.0.1.258",
          "CNP": "0.0.1.491",
          "CBL": "0.0.1.4"
        }

}
```

Above is main json file where I want to update values for "B","S","C","T","I" to be take from below file

["B": "3.11.0.904.175","S": "3.11.0.183","C": "3.11.0.029","T: 3.11.0.007"].

Want to see updated main json file as below

```
{
 "Section": [
    {
      "Update": "Y",
      "header": "Revision History",
      "setitle": " Table A",
      "subtitle": "Region 101",
      "Table": "RegionCode101",
      "Action": "InsertRegion",
      "B": "3.11.0.904.175",
      "S": "3.11.0.183",
      "C": "3.11.0.029",
      "T": "3.11.0.007",
      "I": "0.0.0.300",
      "IN": "0.0.1.491",
      "IPNB": "0.0.2.398",
      "CH": "0.0.1.258",
      "CNP": "0.0.1.491",
      "CBL": "0.0.1.4"
    },
{
          "Update": "Y",
          "header": "Revision History",
          "setitle": " Table A",
          "subtitle": "Region 101",
          "Table": "RegionCode101",
          "Action": "InsertRegion",
          "B": "3.11.0.904.175",
          "S": "3.11.0.183",
          "C": "3.11.0.029",
          "T": "3.11.0.007",
          "I": "0.0.0.300",
          "IN": "0.0.1.491",
          "IPNB": "0.0.2.398",
          "CH": "0.0.1.258",
          "CNP": "0.0.1.491",
          "CBL": "0.0.1.4"
        }
```

}

Looking to update multiple values in both sections as per above output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
check = {
 "Section": [
    {
      "Update": "Y",
      "header": "Revision History",
      "setitle": " Table A",
      "subtitle": "Region 101",
      "Table": "RegionCode101",
      "Action": "InsertRegion",
      "B": "1.0.0.9.3",
      "S": "1.0.0.8",
      "C": "1.0.0.1",
      "T": "1.0.0.3",
      "I": "0.0.0.300",
      "IN": "0.0.1.491",
      "IPNB": "0.0.2.398",
      "CH": "0.0.1.258",
      "CNP": "0.0.1.491",
      "CBL": "0.0.1.4"
    },
 ]
}
     
check['Section'][0]['B'] = "3.11.0.904.175"
check['Section'][0]['S'] = "3.11.0.183"
check['Section'][0]['C'] = "3.11.0.029"
check['Section'][0]['T'] = "3.11.0.007"

check
```

output is

```
{'Section': [{'Update': 'Y',
   'header': 'Revision History',
   'setitle': ' Table A',
   'subtitle': 'Region 101',
   'Table': 'RegionCode101',
   'Action': 'InsertRegion',
   'B': '3.11.0.904.175',
   'S': '3.11.0.183',
   'C': '3.11.0.029',
   'T': '3.11.0.007',
   'I': '0.0.0.300',
   'IN': '0.0.1.491',
   'IPNB': '0.0.2.398',
   'CH': '0.0.1.258',
   'CNP': '0.0.1.491',
   'CBL': '0.0.1.4'}]}
```

Comment: How can i use it to update multiple sections ?

Comment: with a for loop,

check[Section][key] = value